# Can't reach aspnet core application on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, asp.net-core

I published my aspnet core application to an IIS server following the official guide and that all worked fine, when I put the hostname and IP for the IIS in my own machine's hosts file.

However, now that it's all ready, I need others on the network to be able to reach it as well, so I put the hostname in the network DNS, just like I usually do with all my websites.

But now I'm not able to reach the application at all - I'm presuming this is because of the IIS-Kestrel reverse proxy, as the IIS server is now trying to lookup requests using the DNS A-record, which just points to itself.

How do I make this work, so that I can use a network DNS record?

**Update:**

It seems that the problem is with special characters in the hostname (specifically ø).

Changing the binding and network DNS to a hostname that doesn't contain this special character seems to work.

**Settings:**

IIS Binding on http://mysite.domain.dk (80)

With no DNS records in our network DNS, I can reach the app on my *own* machine by putting ip/hostname in my hosts file and browsing http://mysite.domain.dk

As soon as I put the A-record in the network DNS, I'm unable to reach it.

I am (of course) unable to reach the app from the IIS server without any entries in the server hostname, because the server doesn't know where to point http://mysite.domain.dk - however, when I put in a binding to the local server network IP (192.168.17.73) I can reach it here both from the server and client.

Putting in the A-record in network DNS I can still reach the app from IP - both server and client, but unable to reach it through hostname.

**Edit: code and settings**

**Program.cs**

```
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:4561")
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())                
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
```

**project.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "SimpleImpersonation": "2.0.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Configuration": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config",
      "Views",
      "logs",
      "app.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=---;Initial Catalog=---;User ID=---;Password=---" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: No, IIS does not perform any DNS-resolutions during acting as proxy for Kestrel.

Comment: Okay. But that is literally the only thing that changed from when it worked till it didn't. Then I'm completely at a loss for why it isn't working

Comment: Check everything again. Are other computers able to connect to app using you machinename? Are IP-connections works (http://192.168...)? May be your machine now have different address from DHCP Server etc. If not - show your `web.config`, `program.cs`, `project.json` files and provide details about DNS hostname, IIS configuration (bindings to hostnames) and urls your are trying to access your app.

Comment: I updated with info. I really don't see what else could be the issue. Pinging the hostname points to the server IP, so I know the DNS is updated and correct.

Comment: That's very interesting.... So you have 2 machines - your dev with IIS and client. Oh, and 3rd - DNS server. When you put DNS entries in your `hosts` - you reach the app. When you put same records to DNS server - nobody reach and app (but it still reachable by IP). And if your remove non-latin character from site name - app "magically" become accessible with all scenarios. I have no idea what is wrong... Try to add records to `hosts` file on client machine - will it see your app?

Comment: It seems to be an incompatibility with non-latin characters. I can't even use URL Rewrite to rewrite that one non-latin char. Replace that char with anything else and everything works.